# reference error: cant find variable react native

Tags: react-native, expo

having trouble figuring out the error. how do i get rid of it?
reference error: cant find variable: lawncare. it doesnt provide much detail and I cant debug the error

....

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer , createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import ProductScreen from './src/components/productScreen';
import UserDashboard from './src/components/userDashboard';
import LoginScreen from './src/components/loginScreen';
import ForgotPassword from './src/components/forgotPassword';
import SignUpScreen from './src/components/signUp';
import {Provider as AuthProvider} from './src/redux/authContext';
import LawnCareScreen from './src/components/lawnCare';
import CarDetailScreen from './src/components/carDetail';



const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    loginFlow:createStackNavigator({
      Login: LoginScreen,
      SignUp: SignUpScreen,
      Password: ForgotPassword,
    }),
    Products: ProductScreen,
    Dashboard: UserDashboard,
    CarDetail: CarDetailScreen,
    LawnCare: LawnCareScreen
  }

)


const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App/>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

my navigation screen links to the product screen through react navigation

```
 ....import React, {Component}from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, View ,Text, ScrollView,ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
    import {Card} from 'react-native-elements';
    import {FontAwesome, Entypo, FontAwesome5, Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import Spacer from './spacer';




    const ProductScreen = ({navigation}) => {
        console.log(navigate)
    
        return ( 
    <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/backgroundColor.jpg')} style={Styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
    <Card>
     <View style={Styles.spacing}>
         <Text style={Styles.title}>Services</Text>
         <Spacer/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("CarDetail")}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <FontAwesome name='car' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Vehicle Detailing</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Spacer/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("LawnCare")}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Entypo name='flower' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Commercial Lawn Care</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Spacer/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('http://timbumperllc.zohosites.com/')}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <FontAwesome5 name='pills' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Pharmaceuticals</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Spacer/>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Entypo name='credit-card' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Credit Repair</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
            <Spacer/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('https://moefitness33.com/')}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Ionicons name='md-fitness' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Personal Fitness</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            {/* <Spacer/> */}
        {/* <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Entypo name='home' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Brokerage with Saks</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
            <Spacer/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('https://www.catchthesehands-massage.com/')}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Entypo name='hand' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Massage with Catch These Hands</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Spacer/>
        {/* <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <FontAwesome name='scissors' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Grooming with New York</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
            {/* <Spacer/> */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('http://yalajets.com/')}>
        <View style={Styles.background}>
        <Entypo name='aircraft' size={24} style={Styles.icons}/>
        <Text style={Styles.name}>Luxury Private Flights with Yala Jets</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
            </Card>
            </ScrollView>
            </ImageBackground>
    
        )
    };
    
    const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex:1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent:'center'
        },
        image1:{
            width: 175,
            height:175,
            marginTop:200 
        },
        background: {
            backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
            height: 80,
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginHorizontal:19,
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadowRadius:3,
            shadowColor: 'black'
        },
        name: {
            fontSize: 15,
            fontStyle: ('new times roman', 'italic'),
            alignSelf: 'center'
            
        },
        icons:{
            paddingLeft:5,
            paddingTop: 5
        },
        title: {
    fontSize:15,
    fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Heavy',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
    color: 'red'
        }
    
    })
    
    export default ProductScreen;
```

and the product screen links to lawn care screen. however the navigation screen is not reading it.

```
    ....import React from 'react'
    import {View,StyleSheet, ImageBackground, ScrollView,Linking,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import {Text, Card} from 'react-native-elements';
    import Spacer from './spacer';
    
    
    
    const lawnCare = ({Children}) => {
    return (
    <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/landscapeBack.png')} style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
    <Card containerStyle={{ height: 725,width:325, marginBottom:100 , marginTop:50, borderRadius: 10,backgroundColor: 'rgba(205, 199, 199, .3)'}}
    style={styles.boxWithShadow} >
        <Text style={styles.title}>Landscaping Services</Text>
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}> ☑️ Landscape Maintenance</Text>
            <Spacer/>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}> ☑️ Landscape Installation</Text>
            <Spacer/>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}> ☑️ Tree Care</Text>
            <Spacer/>
            <Text style={styles.title}>We offer a Monthly maintenance Plan</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Or a one time project</Text>
        </View>
        <Spacer/>
        <Spacer/>
        <Spacer/>
    <View style={styles.background}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('mailto:info@luxuryvipsvc.com')}>
            <Text style={styles.emailLink}>Email us for a quote</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </Card>
    </ScrollView>
    </ImageBackground>
    )
    };
    
    LawnCare.navigationOptions = {
        headerShown: false
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        spacer: {
            margin: 12
        },
        container: {
            flex:1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent:'center'
        },
        image1:{
            width: 175,
            height:175,
            marginTop:200 
        },
        title: {
            fontSize:26,
            fontFamily: 'Cochin',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            marginTop: 15,
            color: 'black'
                },
            emailLink: {
            fontSize:20,
            fontFamily: 'Cochin',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            marginTop: 15,
            color: 'white'
            },
            paragraph:{
            fontSize:18,
            fontFamily: 'Cochin',
            alignSelf: 'baseline',
            marginTop: 15,
            color: 'black'
            },
            background: {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                height: 80,
                borderRadius: 10,
                marginHorizontal:19,
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadowRadius:3,
                shadowColor: 'black'
            }
            
    });
    
    export default lawnCare;
```

Comment: You are exporting lawnCare as a component but importing it as LawnCareScreen.

Comment: I switched it and the error is the same. I ran a debugger and found this 'Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:16053/d1242870-fa5a-402e-84e9-527479275b4f
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
(node:35726) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
warning.js:32
/Users/siranaba/Desktop/luxvipllc/Luxury-/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:1
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';'

Comment: Do you still have this error: `reference error: cant find variable: lawncare` ?